# Placement of an item in memory

Tags: c++, pointers, reinterpret-cast

Help me please. I allocate memory as follows (T is template type)

```
T * ptr = reinterpret_cast<T*>(operator new (sizeof(T));
```

And after that I want to put an element into this memory; Am I write if I do it in this way?

```
new (p) T(elem);
```

(elem has type T)

UPD: sorry, it's a mistake that I forget to write operator new

Comment: No, `reinterpret_cast` does **not** allocate memory! Don't know why you think it does, but it may be time to refresh some basics.

Comment: Does this compile?

Comment: The reinterpret_cast line sets `ptr` to point to a memory location a few bytes after memory-location zero.  That's not a region of memory the program is allowed to access, and in most systems trying to dereference that memory location will lead to an immediate crash.

Comment: It seems to me like you might need to take a step or two back, and refresh some of your knowledge about pointers and dynamic allocation. Perhaps invest in [a couple of good books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282) to read as well.

Comment: What's the end goal you want to accomplish so that we can help direct you to the correct method.

Comment: You may be looking for "placement new"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`reinterpret_cast` does not allocate memory. I don't know how you got the impression that it does.

```
T * ptr = reinterpret_cast<T*>((sizeof(T));
```

This (assuming it is supported in the first place) takes the size of the type `T` which is an integer value and reinterprets it in an implementation-defined matter as a pointer-to-`T` value.

So if e.g. the size of `T` is `16`, then `ptr` will probably be a pointer to the address `16`.

This clearly makes no sense.

The usual function to dynamically allocate memory to place objects into later is `operator new`:

```
void* mem_ptr = operator new(sizeof(T));
T* ptr = new(mem_ptr) T(elem);
```